# How to set X11 Window Class on application startup

Tags: linux, command-line, x11, gui, wayland

I have an application that doesn't set its own x11 window class, is there an easy way to do this from the command line? I've searched around for an x11 command to do it and haven't been able to find anything.

Example:

```
some_command --window-class 'NewWindowClass' --run MY_PROGRAM
```

Answer (score 0):

The application sets the class when creating the windows.

This means ultimately the application determines if you can set the class, and if yes, with what commandline option(s). There is no universal option.

In particular, you cannot do this from another application (unless you start doing tricky things with preloading libraries, and intercepting the XCreateWindow call etc.)

However, if the application use Xt commandline parsing, the option `-class` will usually work (unless disabled by the application).

Comment: Ugh that's a bit disappointing. The program in question is legacy software and ported from another platform so the original devs had no purpose in setting the window class, I guess I'll be doing some research to figure out how to modify the program itself to achieve this properly since I have the source code.

Comment: Doing it when you have the source code is very easy.

Comment: Aside from xterm, which application provides a `-class` option?

Answer (score 0):

I also needed this functionality. How about something like:

```bash
xclock &
PID=$!
xdotool search --sync --all --pid ${PID} --name '.*' set_window --classname "A" set_window --class "B"
```

It works by:

- Launching an X application (in your case would be `MY_PROGRAM`) in the background
- Saving the Process ID (PID) of the launched application into a variable
- Using `xdotool` to find the X window ID from the PID (it even waits until the window appears first using the `sync` option)
- Using `xdotool` to set the `classname` and `class` of the window

Note: We have to do `xdotool search --sync --all --pid ${PID} --name '.*'` because seems `xdotool` does not support a shorter invocation like `xdotool search --sync --pid ${PID}` to search just based on PID.

Also, this may not work as it states in the `xdotool` docs:

> This may not work for some X applications that do not set this metadata on its windows

If you have a reliable way of getting the X window ID yourself you can simply do (change `0x0620000a` to your own X window ID):

```bash
xdotool set_window --classname "A" 0x0620000a set_window --class "B" 0x0620000a
```

To check that it worked you can do:

```bash
wmctrl -l -x -p | grep xclock
```

Which should output something like:

```bash
0x0640000a  0 993355 A.B                   pc xclock
```